# How i can process every block of an image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, analysis

how cand i apply Box Counting Algorithm in each box of an image ?(https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30329-hausdorff--box-counting--fractal-dimension)
To be more precise, i want to crop an image (e.g 1024x1024) in multiple blocks, let's say 10, because 2^10=1024. After that i want to apply algorithm in each piece,and so on. The final step is stored the result into a array. 
I heard I heard about a function called blockproc, but i don't know how to compute fun parameter.Thanks in advice.

Comment: It will probably be easier if you have access to each block in your image directly.  Once you use the above duplicate, you will have a cell array of blocks - one for each non-overlapping patch in your image.  You can then use the linked algorithm and apply that to each block.

Comment: If i use:  fun = @(block_struct) ...
   std2(block_struct.data) * ones(size(block_struct.data)); After that I1 = blockproc(I,[512 512],fun);

Comment: "let's say 10, because 2^10=1024" -> `1024/10 = 102.4`, it doesn't divide evenly. `2^10` is not the same as `2*10`. You should probably pick a size that is a power of 2, because `2^10 / 2^n = 2^(10-n)`, which is a whole number.

Comment: It's ok to use T=blockproc(I,[2^10 / 2^n = 2^(10-n],fun) ? After that R=hsusdim(T) , n=[1024 1024] . But how to compute handler function "fun" to mem the result for each block ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How i processed block by block an image with dimension 1024x1024 and then apply Box Counting Algorithm in each processed block ? The result may be an array with calculation value. Thanks in advance.